# How to style a vertical line with rounded edges?

Tags: css, sass

[image]

I need to have a vertical line with rounded edges. I used border-left but border-radius doesn't work for having rounded edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's quite a few ways to do this with CSS. You can use a span and just style it with height and width or you can use a pseudo element like :before or :after and style that.

Here's the span for example:

```css
    div {
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px;
        align-items: center;
    }
    span {
        height: 40px;
        width: 5px;
        background-color: #FECC01;
        border-radius: 99px;
        margin: 0 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
        9:30am
    </p>
    <span></span>
    <p>
        School Tour
    </p>
</div>
```

No matter which way you go the styling of the shape will be the same, height, width, background-color.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can make it Horizontal:

```css
    div {
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px;
        align-items: center;
    }
    span {
        height: 5px;
        width: 55px;
        background-color: #FECC01;
        border-radius: 100px;
        margin: 0 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
        9:30am
    </p>
    <span></span>
    <p>
        School Tour
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).